# How to represent Objc-C NSUInteger[] = {0,1,2} in Swift as UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt>?

Tags: objective-c, swift

Objc-C header definition:

`- (int)printPDFAtPath:(NSString *)pdfPath pages:(NSUInteger [])indexes length:(NSUInteger)length copy:(int)nCopy;`

Sample objc-C code to use this function:

`NSUInteger pageIndexes[] = {0};
printResult = [self.ptp printPDFAtPath:selectedPDFFilePath pages:pageIndexes length:length copy:self.numberOfPaper];`

Swift expects:

`func printPDF(atPath pdfPath: String!, pages indexes: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt>!, length: UInt, copy nCopy: Int32) -> Int32`

How do I represent `NSUInteger pageIndexes[] = {0};` in Swift as a `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt>`?

Comment: maybe using  `indexes: inout [UInt] ` is good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply pass  a Swift `[UInt]` array as in-out argument  with `&`, this passes the address of the array element storage to the (Objective-)C function:

```
var pageIndexes: [UInt] = [1, 2, 3]
ptp.printPDF(atPath: "path", pages: &pageIndexes, length: UInt(pageIndexes.count), copy: 1)
```

For more information, see

- [Using Imported C Functions in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/using_imported_c_functions_in_swift),
- [Interacting with C Pointers](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=6).